# react setState array of object using map doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have problem doing a setState changing value of a nested array of object. Below code suppose
to change question of id 2 to answer: true but it did not, what's wrong?

```
this.state = {
  questions: [
    {
      id: 1,
      answer: ''
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      answer: ''
    },
  ]
}
//I have a click event somewhere
this.setState(
  {
    questions: this.state.questions.map(q => {
      if (q.id === 2) {
        return {
          ...q,
          answer: true
        }
      } else {
        return { ...q }
      }
    })
  },
  console.log(this.state.questions[1]) // did not see id of 2 being changed to true?
)
```

Comment: @Finesse it's the state, updated

Comment: Actually, OP updates the state correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `console.log(this.state.questions[1])` line is executed before the `this.setState` line is executed, that's why the old state is printed to the console. You should put the line inside a function to delay the execution:

```
this.setState(..., () => console.log(this.state.questions[1]));
```

Also it is recommended to use a function as the first argument if the changed state is derived from the current state because React doesn't apply the new state immediately therefore `this.state` can be outdated when React applies the new state:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  questions: state.questions.map(q => {
    if (q.id === 2) {
      return {...q, answer: true};
    }
    return q;
  })
}), () => {
  console.log(this.state.questions[1]);
});
```

Comment: Err, probably a missing part here :) `questions.map` should be `state.questions.map`. Right? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking your `setState` callback. Try like this:

```
this.setState(
  {
    questions: this.state.questions.map(q => {
      if (q.id === 2) {
        return {
          ...q,
          answer: true
        };
      }
      return { ...q };
    })
  },
  () => console.log(this.state.questions[1]) // did not see id of 2 being changed to true?
);
```

Though, since you are using the current state to update your state again, it would be better to use functional setState.

```
this.setState(
  currentState => ({
    questions: currentState.questions.map(q => {
      if (q.id === 2) {
        return {
          ...q,
          answer: true
        };
      }
      return { ...q };
    })
  }),
  () => console.log(this.state.questions[1])
);
```

Also, you don't have to log your state in a callback to `setState`. You can log your state in your `render` method without struggling `setState`'s callback.

```
this.setState(
  currentState => ({
    questions: currentState.questions.map(q => {
      if (q.id === 2) {
        return {
          ...q,
          answer: true
        };
      }
      return { ...q };
    })
  })
);

....

render() {
    console.log( this.state );
    ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because Array.map returns an array. Try:

```js
this.setState(
  {
    questions: this.state.questions.map(q => {
      if (q.id === 2) {
        q.answer = true;
      } 
      return q;
    })
  },
  console.log(this.state.questions[1]) // did not see id of 2 being changed to true?
)
```

Comment: Hi @Charlie. As a crucial suggestion, do not mutate your state, your object properties like that using React, Redux, etc. Never. OP is doing right.

Comment: yeah you're right: immutability in objects, that's Redux's principle

Comment: Also, in React's state :) Good luck on your developing journey.